# Encrypt String into Numbers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, encryption

How can I convert or Encrypt strings into numbers

eg: addedToStage into/as -1820302713

Comment: It's not encryption, because -1820302713 has less information than "addedToStage", so you cannot get a string out of it. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: var _loc1:String = Encrypt.decode(-1820302713);
trace(_loc1); // is "addedToStage"
I want to convert/ encrypt strings into numbers

Comment: @user1209015 Sounds like you already know how to do this, using Encrypt.decode().  Could you edit your question to be more specific?

Comment: @Brian updated the question can you tell me how this can be done

Comment: Wait a sec, there isn't an Encrypt class in the standard SDK!  @user1209015, where is this class coming from?

Comment: @Joseph forget SDK, How to encrypt strings into numbers and decrypt numbers back to strings

Comment: Well how did you get your example above to work?  That is, you wrote "var _loc1:String = Encrypt.decode(-1820302713); trace(_loc1);"  So what's the problem?  Or, is that not real code, and just an example of what you want to do?  And really, you need to answer Artjom B.'s question: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Consider the above as example. Now I just want to encrypt a given string and the output should be in number format. Is this possible, if so how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no single/main encryption method.There can be many encryption methods.You can create your own encryption methods.here is a simple one that I created.this example ,encrypts string using a number password.(encrypting string into number is a bad practice.I used string to string):

```
function encrypt(s:String,password:uint):String{
    var ret:String="";
    for(var i:uint=0;i<s.length;i++){

      var added:uint=s.charCodeAt(i)+password;
      added=added>uint.MAX_VALUE?added-uint.MAX_VALUE:added;

       ret+=String.fromCharCode(added)

    }
    return ret;
}
function decrypt(s:String,password:uint):String{
    var ret:String="";
    for(var i:uint=0;i<s.length;i++){

      var added:int=s.charCodeAt(i)-password;
      added=added<0?added+uint.MAX_VALUE:added;

      ret+=String.fromCharCode(added)

    }
    return ret;
}
```

now, let's try this interactive code:

```
trace(encrypt("StackOverFlow.com",50));//¦¨¤x¡©`¡
trace(decrypt("¦¨¤x¡©`¡",50));//StackOverFlow.com
```

Here I used to convert letters, to other letters with char code +password.you can have your custom methods.

I H☺P E this helps.

Comment: thanks, I shifted to XORChiper & base64 and along side I will use urs as i found its simple.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. I had accepted your answer.

Comment: There is a  tick button.on the upper left side of my post. if you accept my answer, you should click on that tick.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't know that, Clicked now :)